# Google App Engine - updating backends without shutdown

Tags: google-app-engine

When I update dynamic backends in GAE, existing instances are shut down, cancelling current requests. Is there a way to update the backends without cancelling existing requests (similar to updating a normal app)?

I update the backends using:

```
appcfg.py backends . update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy a different version and then switch.
Also consider the using of [traffic splitting](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting).

**UPDATE**: This will work only with [modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) I think. Backends now deprecated.